# Problem while using links() and nav tabs : Redirecting to page 2 of other tabs while it does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using nav tabs of bootstrap (I have 5 tabs) and paginate function `links()`. If I have 2 page in the first tab, and I click on next to go to the 2nd page, and then I'm going to another tab, it will be display nothing even if I have data inside it. Why ? Because inside the url, there is the `?page=2` of the 1st tab. It does not erase when I'm changing tabs.

Does someone know how can I be able to resolve this please ?

Example :

```xml
<nav class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center nav-justified">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Test1</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Test2</a>
</nav>
```

Content of the tab pane :

```xml
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="test1">
    <p>test 1 i'm here</p>
    @foreach($tests as $test1)
        {{ $test1->name }}
    @endforeach
    {!! $tests->links() !!}
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="test2">
    <p>test 2 i'm here</p>
    @foreach($tests as $test2)
        {{ $test2->name }}
    @endforeach
    {!! $tests->links() !!}
</div>
```

I have a `paginate(1)`, so if inside my `test1` tab, I have more than 1 line (imagine 4), and I go to the page 4, and then I click to the tab `test2`, it will display that I do not have data even if I have 1 or more (less than 4).

Cordially

EDIT SOLUTION :

I've found the solution, here is an example to put into your controller where I use the `paginate` function :

```
$users = User::paginate(10, ['*'], 'users');

$posts = Post::paginate(10, ['*'], 'posts');
```

doc: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Comment: Please show us code, aka [mre].

Comment: i've edited my question. But its quit difficult since I'm using Laravel. Hopes it help.

Comment: I copied your code line by line and it works on my end. Are you sure there's nothing wrong on your end? Does the console say anything?

Comment: Well, did you have more than 1 element in each tab ? Normally, if you have more than 1 element in one tab and less in the other one, it should show nothing. I don't really understand why I've this problem